# How can I scale down everything that Lilypond is outputting?

Tags: lilypond

How can I scale down/shrink everything that Lilypond is outputting so that I can fit more material on each page? I tried using

```
\layout{
    #(layout-set-staff-size XX)
}
```

inside the `\score{}` block (where `XX` can be any number), to just change the staff size, but this screws up the overall look and relative dimensions, so it's not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want

```
#(set-global-staff-size XX)
```

Here is the [lilypond 2.19 staff size documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/setting-the-staff-size) (also works in 2.18).

Note that you don't put this command inside the `\layout` block; the following is what I've tested/verified (v2.18) in constructing this answer:

```
#(set-global-staff-size 36 )
\relative c'{
  c d e g f g a c e e d2
 }
```

Comment: `"Here is the lilypond 2.19 staff size documentation (also works in 2.18)."` I think this is a little confusing, since his example is the second option there.  I had the same problem once I did not notice this was the `2.19` documentation and the second option is not working properly in `2.18`

Comment: @nath I referenced the 2.19 (current) documentation, but on my own machine I'm running 2.18, so that is how I verified it.  It worked for me.